# stop uiview rotation

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a tableview and detail view app, in the tableview I have this to stop it from being able to rotate.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return false;
}
```

so the main view should always be in portrait mode.

however the subview is able to change rotation freely.. if i go from the detail view while in landscape view to the parent tableview then the tableview appears in landscape and cannot rotate back.. hoping someone can help me fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling it never to rotate, what you actually want is:

```
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
```

which says it should only rotate when it's to portrait orientation.

Comment: ah, yes I see. however this is giving me an error I typed this **return (UIInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)** and now its saying **expected expression ')'*

Comment: its working.. 

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);}

Comment: cheers :) thanks for that.. didn't solve my actual issue but helped my app work abit better :)